# Why can't a 9 vertex graph whose complement is in 3 components be planar?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with 9 vertices whose complement, $\overline{G}$, has three components.

I've read that it can't be planar, but am having trouble completing a proof.

Most ways of distributing the 9 vertices among the 3 components of $\overline{G}$ would force $G$ to be non-planar, it is clear to me. For example, if 6 vertices were in one component, 2 in another and 1 in the last, then in $G$ any 3 vertices from that 6-vertex component would be completely connected to the vertices from the other 2 components, i.e. $K_{3,3}$ would be a subgraph of $G$, so $G$ would be non-planar.

This argument works when the largest component has 5 vertices, 4 vertices, or even 3 vertices.

That leaves one case: when 7 vertices are connected into a component in $\overline{G}$ and the other 2 vertices are isolated points. Why must $G$ be non-planar in this case?

Comment: Hint: Look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2672614/is-the-complement-of-a-c7-graph-planar-or-non-planar/2672647#2672647

Comment: So it's the connected 7-vertex graph itself that is either non-planar or has a non-planar complement?

Comment: In your final case, the graph will be $K_{2,7}$ plus as many edges that you can join the $7$ points; the $7$ points will form a cycle & the complement of this is the graph given in the previous reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, the statement is wrong: $G$ can be planar.

Assume that the component of size 7 in $\overline{G}$ is the clique; then $G$ is the tripartite graph $K_{1,1,7}$, which is planar:

[image: K177]